# curl unable to obtain local certificate on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, openssl, curl, certificates

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with Unity desktop. It is fully updated setup with latest version of ca-certificates and latest available version of firefox.

The other day I was trying to download something from Harper's website and noticed that curl is complaining about certificate.

If I execute this cli:

```
curl -v https://harpers.org/wp-content/themes/harpers/images/logoBlack.png
```

I get the following output:

```
  * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  *   Trying 54.243.234.21...
  * Connected to harpers.org (54.243.234.21) port 443 (#0)
  * successfully set certificate verify locations:
  *   CAfile: none
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
  * SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
  * SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
  * Closing connection 0
  curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Which is silly since Harper's certificate is issued by DigiCert and Firefox ships with that certificate.

[image: Certificate Screenshot]

So I did this manually just to see if it works:

```
  cd /tmp/
  wget https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt
  openssl x509 -in DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt -inform DER -out DigiCertGlobalRootCA.pem -outform PEM

  wget https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt
  openssl x509 -in DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt -inform DER -out DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.pem -outform PEM

  cat DigiCertGlobalRootCA.pem >> DigiCertGlobalRootCASHA2SecureServerCA.pem
  cat DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.pem >> DigiCertGlobalRootCASHA2SecureServerCA.pem

  curl -v --cacert DigiCertGlobalRootCASHA2SecureServerCA.pem \
       https://harpers.org/wp-content/themes/harpers/images/logoBlack.png \
       -o logoBlack.png 2> down.log
```

And got this:

```
  * Connected to harpers.org (54.243.234.21) port 443 (#0)
  * successfully set certificate verify locations:
  *   CAfile: DigiCertGlobalRootCASHA2SecureServerCA.pem
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  } [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  { [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
  { [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  { [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  { [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  } [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  } [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  } [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  { [data not shown]
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  { [data not shown]
  * SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
  * Server certificate:
  *      subject: C=US; ST=New York; L=New York; O=Harper's Magazine Foundation; CN=*.harpers.org
  *      start date: 2016-01-11 00:00:00 GMT
  *      expire date: 2019-01-15 12:00:00 GMT
  *      subjectAltName: harpers.org matched
  *      issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
  *      SSL certificate verify ok.
  > GET /wp-content/themes/harpers/images/logoBlack.png HTTP/1.1
  > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
  > Host: harpers.org
  > Accept: */*
  > 
  < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  < Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 20:20:38 GMT
  * Server Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
  < Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
  < Last-Modified: Fri, 14 Dec 2012 10:10:30 GMT
  < ETag: "24d7-4d0cd3dc47180"
  < Accept-Ranges: bytes
  < Content-Length: 9431
  < Content-Type: image/png
  < 
  { [data not shown]

  100  9431  100  9431    0     0  12707      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12710
  * Connection #0 to host harpers.org left intact
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem

```sh
wget -P '/tmp/' -nv 'https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt'
openssl x509 -in '/tmp/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt' -inform DER \
             -out '/tmp/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.pem' -outform PEM
sudo cp -uv '/tmp/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.pem' '/etc/ssl/certs'
sudo c_rehash
```